# sort a List based on a parameter available in another class

Tags: java, comparator

I have some design problems with Java `Comparator` Interface.

I have a class which contains a `Set` of a simple custom data structure:

```
class data {  
    Long ID;  
    int Priority;  
    ...
}
```

`ID`s are unique, so it is possible to get the whole data using `ID‍‍‍‍‍`.

and the container class:

```
class Container {
    Set<data> mySet = ...;
    List<Long> myList = ...;
    ...
}
```

for some inevitable reasons, I need to keep a sorted `List` of `data` IDs in parallel. I need the `List` to be sorted by `Priority`.

Since, the `Comparator` should compare `Priority`s it should implements `Comparator<int>`. But the `List` only contains `ID`s and the `Priority`s are not available directly.

This is the problem. There is only `ID` in the `List`. Therefore, the Comparator class has no access to `Priority`.

How can I design such concept?

Comment: you want orange juice but you dont supply orange, huh?

Comment: lol, yeah. but the orange is available somewhere else! :D
I just don't know how to access it!

Comment: Do you have list of instances what you created, somewhere??

Comment: yes, they are available in the `mySet`.

Comment: Then you need to find the `object` from that Set for each `Id` and check its `Priority`..  have a `getDataById()` method in your class.

Comment: The comparator is another class, and has no access to Container instance. So, the way you suggesting, the only working solutions is to make Container a Singelton or Static (which is not simply possible). am I right?

Comment: @MBZ.. You have to make your List<Data> static.. See my code below.. to get an idea how it should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something that smells like higher order functions. That is, make a static function that takes a map of sorts from Long to int (which is the priority) or data and returns a new Comparator.

The class Foo has a static method `getComparator` which takes an Orange. An Orange is a class that has a method `getPriority` which takes an ID an return the corresponding priority. The `getComparator` method constructs a new `Comparator` object. The new `Comparator` object's `compare` method takes two IDs. It looks up the corresponding priorities of the two IDs and compares them.

```
public interface Orange {
    // Looks up id and returns the corresponding Priority.
    public int getPriority(Long id);
}

public class Foo {
    public static Comparator<Long> getComparator(final Orange orange) {
        return new Comparator<Long>() {
            public int compare(Long id1, Long id2) {
                // Get priority through orange, or
                // Make orange juice from our orange.
                // You may want to compare them in a different way.
                return orange.getPriority(id1) - orange.getPriority(id2);
        };
    }
}
```

My java is a bit rusty so the code may be flawed. The general idea should work, though.

Usage:

```
// This is defined somewhere. It could be a local variable or an instance
// field or whatever. There's no exception (except is has to be in scope).
Collection c = ...;
...
Orange orange = new Orange() {
    public int getPriority(Long id) {
        // Insert code that searches c.mySet for an instance of data
        // with the desired ID and return its Priority
    }
};
Collections.sort(c.myList, Foo.getComparator(orange));
```

I have not given an example on how an Orange could look.

Comment: I really didn't get your answer :( Can you please add more details?

Comment: Yes. Can you give some hints on what's missing?

Comment: I added some naming to my question. It would be very nice if you rewrite your code in my naming :)

Comment: @MBZ, how about now? Is it better? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: not working :(
it seems that it is not possible to cast `Comparator<Int>` to `Comparator<Long>`.

Comment: @MBZ Sorry, that was a brainfart. It should have been Comparator<Long> both places.

Comment: Thanks, it was an incredible solutions :)

Comment: @ReyCharles.. But in your solution, your `getPriority(Long id)` method will look up for an `Orange` with that `id`, and return the instance.. But where will it look.. There has to be a `List<Orange>` somewhere right??

Comment: Yes. But you can create an Orange instance in your code that will look up based on a specific instance of Container. I will try flesh out my example a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. There doesn't have to be a `List<Orange>` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a `List<Data>` stored somewhere.. In Comparator, you need to invoke a `getDataById` method from your data class, and sort through Priority..

Check the below code.. I have used a single class for many purpose..

Ideally you would want to **break it into more classes**.. But this is just a **Demo**, how to achieve what you want..

```
class Container {
    // List of Data  instances created..
    // This list has to be static, as it is for a class, 
    // and not `instance specific`
    public static List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();

    // List of Ids, that you want to sort.
    private List<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    // Populate both the list..

    // Have a method that will iterate through static list to 
    // find Data instance for a particular id

    public static Data getDataById(long id) {
        // Find Data with id from the list

        // Return Data
    }

    public void sortList() {
        Collections.sort(idList, new MyComparator());
    }
}

public MyComparator implements Comparator<Long> {

    public int compare(Long int1, Long int2) {
        Data data1 = Container.getDataById(int1);
        Data data2 = Container.getDataById(int2);

        return data1.getPriority() - data2.getPriority();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I am not able to redefine the Container class as `Static`. The `List` must vary in different instances.

Comment: @MBZ.. That is meaningless.. How can you have a different list of instance created for every instance.. No of instances created has to be same for all the instances.. Actually it is class-specific..

Comment: @MBZ.. And you are not making your `Container` class Static.. But the List that holds your instances `Static`.. Without that, you cannot achieve what you want..  Unless you use a Database..

Comment: Re our discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826864/binarysearch-method-producing-arrayindexoutofbounds-exception). You suggest he makes mySet static. That's fine, although one could suspect it's not an option for him to change the Container class since it would be easier to just have a List<data> instead of List<Long>. He then says it's not possible for him to do that and you just say that's "meaningless". You also say it's not possible without making it static. That's clearly not true as my answer shows. Hope to see some good answers and comments from you in the future :-)

Comment: It's mostly that you insist he changes his `Container` class and say it's not possible otherwise. Often one works with code one does not control and hence cannot change. You have to accept his terms and try to work out a solution from there.