# binarySearch Method producing "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds" Exception

Tags: java, exception, methods, binary-search, indexoutofboundsexception

I would like to know why this method is giving me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception when I provide a key that is a letter not in my array. It seems to have no problem returning a value if the key is anything other than a letter.

```
public class BinarySearch2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
        String key = "K";
        String found = binarySearch(array, key);
        System.out.println(found);
    }

    public static String binarySearch(String[] array, String key) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = array.length;
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        //int i = 0;

        while (low <= high) {
            //System.out.print(i + " ");
            if (array[mid].compareTo(key) < 0) {
                System.out.println(array[mid].compareTo(key));
                low = mid + 1;
                mid = (low + high)/2;
            }
            else if (array[mid].compareTo(key) > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
                mid = (low + high)/2;
            }
            else
                return array[mid];

            //i++;
        }
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting exception?? Can you post full stack trace..

Comment: Why not use Arrays.binarySearch?

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky.. Might be OP is in initial stages of programming.. If it is, then this way would be better.. He can get himself aware of available methods later on.. After he gains the concept..

Comment: I'm studying Computer Science in college and I'm in the midst of studying for an exam coming up. I'm just trying to understand thing better and go over the concepts we talked about in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `binarySearch` method, you have initialized your `high` to: -

```
int low = 0;
int high = array.length;
int mid = (low + high)/2;
```

Your **high** should actually be: -

```
int high = array.length - 1;
```

Comment: @user1735982.. You can test the code after this change.. It should work.. In fact it works for me.. Still don't know why someone has DownVoted..

Comment: @RohitJain First, I have not downvoted your (or anyone, actually). Personally I think your answer and comments in ["sort a list..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817616/sort-a-list-based-on-a-parameter-available-in-another-class/) were poor. Perhaps your downvoted answers were, well, bad?

Comment: @ReyCharles.. Well, then in that case, don't I deserve to know where I'm wrong?? What good will it do to me, just by downvoting and going away..

Comment: @ReyCharles.. And I would like you to add some comments in the answer which you don't like.. This will also help me improve my understanding.. I am talking about the question you linked to..

Comment: @ReyCharles.. And also the difference between your answer and my answer.. They look the same to me..

Comment: @RohitJain I totally agree that you should know what could be improved. I will add a comment in the other thread.

Comment: Just to be clear I don't think this particular answer deserves downvoting.