# Best way to sort 2 array lists?

Tags: java

I have 2 array lists. One is an array list containing birthdays. The other is an array list of names.

I am sorting the array list of dates in descending order by date using

```
Collections.sort(birthdayList);
```

I want to have the array list of names be sorted in the same order that the birthday list was.

i.e.

unsorted

```
bdaylist   namelist

1/20/1980 - Bob

3/15/1970 - Todd

8/25/1990 - Jeff
```

becomes

sorted

```
3/15/1970 - Todd

1/20/1980 - Bob

8/25/1990 - Jeff
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in Java?

Thank you very much!

Comment: have the object implement `Comparable<T>` and provide your own `compareTo` implementation

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817616/sort-a-list-based-on-a-parameter-available-in-another-class/12817959#12817959) answer could be used.

Answer (score 8):

- Create a Person class with 2 fields: name and birthday.
- Put the persons in a list
- sort with a custom comparator that compares the birthdays

Answer (score 4):

Create a class like this:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private String name;

    private Date date;

    public Person(String name, Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.date.compareTo(o.getDate());
    }
}
```

Then you can sort the list of `Person` objects like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    LinkedList<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person("Name1", new Date())); //Specify different dates
    persons.add(new Person("Name2", new Date()));
    persons.add(new Person("Name3", new Date()));

    Collections.sort(persons);

    //Collections.sort(persons, Collections.reverseOrder()); //Reverse order
}
```

That's it.

Or another alternative is to use `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    }
});
```

Reverse order:

```
Collections.sort(persons, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    }
}));
```

Then you don't need to implement `Comparable<Person>` in your person class.

Answer (score 3):

Don't sort two array lists; sort one array list filled with combined objects containing both the date and the name.  That's really the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers about implementing `Comparable` and using it as the comparator are all indeed correct. But, if this also helps...

According to the [Javadoc for Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), it is noted that sort() uses **Modified Mergesort** as the sorting algorithm. Correct me if I am wrong, but it is widely accepted that Merge Sort achieves the *best* possible running time for the worst-case scenario out of all sorting algorithms out there: O(n log n) (I'm not eliminating the fact that there may be other sort algorithms that also achieve O(n log n) in the worst case).

But, O(n log n) is only the best possible run time for an *unbounded* domain of values. If you have a bound on your domain, then you can get an even better runtime of O(n) using **[Bucket Sort.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)**