# Java Sorting User defined Objects

Tags: java

I want to sort Collection of Objects, which does not implement comparable or comparater interface. The problem is I cannot change the class design because I have only .class(no source code) file. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort by providing a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You don't need to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

See [Collections.sort(List s, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and the [Collections ordering tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) - specifically the section labelled *Comparators*:

> What if you want to sort some objects in an order other than their
>   natural ordering? Or what if you want to sort some objects that don't
>   implement Comparable?

Answer (score 3):

You can use comparator

```
public class ExampleComparator {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    list.add(new Person("shyam",24));
    list.add(new Person("jk",29));
    list.add(new Person("paul",30));
    list.add(new Person("ashique",4));
    list.add(new Person("sreeraj",14));
    for (Person person : list) {
        System.out.println(person.getName()+ "   "+ person.getAge());
    }
    Collections.sort(list,new PersonComparator());
    System.out.println("After sorting");
    for (Person person : list) {
        System.out.println(person.getName()+ "   "+ person.getAge());
    }
}
}




public class Person {
private int age;
private String name;

Person (String name, int age){
    setName(name);
    setAge(age);
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}

public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

@Override
public int compare(Person obj1, Person obj2) {
    return obj1.getAge() - obj2.getAge();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. Your Person object implements Comparator, but the OP can't modify his classes that he needs sorting.

Comment: @BrianAgnew  Before down voting. atleast try to execute this in your machine... Its working here.

Comment: I don't doubt it works. I don't think it answers the specific question, however

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you need to sort `Person` objects list:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

It does not have to implement **Comparable** or **Comparator** interfaces. You can sort it like this:

```
public void someTest() {
    LinkedList<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person());
    //add as many as you want
    Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    });
}
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014952/best-way-to-sort-2-array-lists/13015087#13015087).

Answer (score 1):

**-** Your class doesn't need to implement `Comparable`, but instead, **custom** java.util.Comparator.

**-** Cause `Comparator` is **like comparing the Object outside the Class whose objects are to be compared.**

**-** You will need to use the `Collections's` method `sort()`.

**Eg:**

`Collections.sort(List l , Comparator c)`

**-** `Comparator` is also very useful when we want to sort an object on basis of **More than on one of its attribute**.

Comment: No. His class can't implement another interface. And I'm not convinced that a sortable class implementing Comparator is quite right. That's what Comparable is for

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your class looks moreless like this:

```
class Test {
    public int amount; //field u want to compare

    // ...

}
```

Write your custom comparator for this class:

```
class TestAmountComparator implements Comparator<Test> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Test t1, Test t2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(t1.amount).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(t2.amount))          
    }
}
```

To sort the list of your objects:

```
List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>(myTest); //your Test list
//sorting
Collections.sort(list, new TestAmountComparator()); //sort by amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Collection can be sort by using custom  `Comparator`
(Ex: If you have a class call `Person` and you want to sort according to the person's age)

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        if (o1.getAge() < o2.getAge()){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just sort the list of Persons using this custom Comparator

```
Collections.sort(list, new CustomComparator());
```