# Java Get User input for first name, last name, age, sort by alphabetical and then by age

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to sort 2 array lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014952/best-way-to-sort-2-array-lists)

```
package bubblesort;

import java.util.*;

public class BubbleSort {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> lastnamesList = new ArrayList();
    List<String> firstnamesList = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> ageList = new ArrayList();       
    List<String> fullnamesList = new ArrayList();
    int decider;
    String EOF = "EOF";


    System.out.println("Enter in 0 to sort by Last Name, Enter in 1 to sort by Age");
    decider = input.nextInt();

    /*if(decider == 0)
    {
    System.out.println("Sorting by Last Name");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Please Enter in your Last Name, FirstName, Age: " );
        fullnamesList.add(input2.nextLine());
        }
    Collections.sort(fullnamesList);
    System.out.println("Sorting by Last Name: ");
    System.out.println(fullnamesList);
    }*/ 
    //String[] lastnamesArray = lastnamesList.toArray(new String[lastnamesList.size()]);
    //String[] firstnamesArray = firstnamesList.toArray(new String[firstnamesList.size()]);
    if(decider == 1)
    {
    System.out.println("Sorting by Age");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Please Enter in your Last Name: " );
        lastnamesList.add(input2.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please Enter in your First Name: " );
        firstnamesList.add(input2.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please Enter in your Age: " );
        ageList.add(input.nextInt());

        }

    String[] firstnamesArray = firstnamesList.toArray(new String[firstnamesList.size()]);
    String[] lastnamesArray = lastnamesList.toArray(new String[lastnamesList.size()]);
    fullnamesList.addAll(firstnamesList);
    fullnamesList.addAll(lastnamesList);
    String[] fullnamesArray = fullnamesList.toArray(new String[firstnamesList.size()+lastnamesList.size()]);

    Collections.sort(fullnamesList);
    System.out.println("Sorting by Age");
    System.out.println(fullnamesList);
    }
}
public static void sortStringBubble(String x[])
{
    int j;
    boolean flag = true;
    String temp;

    while(flag)
    {
        flag = false;
        for(j = 0;j < x.length -1 ; j++)
        {
            if (x [j].compareToIgnoreCase(x[j+1])>0)
            {
                temp = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j+1];
                x[j+1] = temp;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

im trying to keep the first name, last name, and age together, but i want it to be sorted alphabetically as one instead of sorting them separately.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The answer shows OP's approach is wrong and only one ArrayList is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
List<String> lastnamesList = new ArrayList();
List<String> firstnamesList = new ArrayList();
List<Integer> ageList = new ArrayList();
```

use

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
```

where `Person` is a class you write yourself. Than there is only one list to sort.

`Person` would have the fields `lastName`, `firstName` and `age`, so they'll always be together.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014952/best-way-to-sort-2-array-lists) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213493/can-i-sort-two-lists-in-relation-to-each-other) post, or some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20sort%20two%20lists).

Comment: I'm fairly new to java so the person class is quite confusing for me, are there any algorithms that can just swap the positions of the name and age according to alphabetical order and keep the fields together

Comment: There's no reasonable alternative to the `Person` class, as there are no algorithms for sorting multiple lists according to the index changes of one list.

Comment: You need a Comparator for the Person class.